# Efficiency in using pandas and parquet

Tags: pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow, ibis

People talk a lot about using [parquet and pandas](https://medium.com/productive-data-science/why-you-should-use-parquet-files-with-pandas-b0ca8cb14d71). And I am trying hard to understand if we can utilize the entire features of parquet files when used with pandas. For instance say I have a big parquet file (partitioned on year) with 30 columns (including year, state, gender, last_name) and many rows. I want to load the parquet file and perform similar computation that follow

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet("file.parquet")
df_2002 = df[df.year == 2002]
df_2002.groupby(["state", "gender"])["last_name"].count()
```

Here in this query only 4 columns (out of 30) and only year `2002` partition is used. It means we just want to bring the columns and rows that are needed for this computation, and something like this is possible in parquet with predicate and projection pushdown (and why we using parquet).

But I am trying to understand how this query behaves in pandas. Does it bring everything into memory the moment we call `df = pd.read_parquet("file.parquet)` ? Or any lazy factor is getting applied here to bring in the projection & predicate pushdown? If this is not the case then what is the point in using pandas with parquet? Any of this is possible with the `arrow package` out there ?

Eventhough I haven't used `dask` just wondering if this kind of situation is handled in  dask as they perform it lazily.

I am sure this kind of situation is handled well in the spark world, but just wondering how these situations are handled in local scenarios with packages like pandas, arrow,dask, ibis etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And I am trying hard to understand if we can utilize the entire features of parquet files when used with pandas.

TL;DR: Yes, but you may have to work harder than if you used something like Dask.

> For instance say I have a big parquet file (partitioned on year)

This is pedantic but a single parquet file is not partitioned on anything.  Parquet "datasets" (collections of files) are partitioned.  For example:

```
my_dataset/year=2002/data.parquet
my_dataset/year=2003/data.parquet
```

> Does it bring everything into memory the moment we call df = pd.read_parquet("file.parquet) ?

Yes.  But...you can do better:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/new_dataset', filters=[[('year','=', 2002)]], columns=['year', 'state', 'gender', 'last_name'])
```

The `filters` keyword will pass the filter down to pyarrow which will apply the filter in a pushdown fashion both to the partition (e.g. to know which directories need to be read) and to the row group statistics.

The `columns` keyword will pass the column selection down to pyarrow which will apply the selection to only read the specified columns from disk.

> Any of this is possible with the arrow package out there ?

Everything in pandas' `read_parquet` file is being handled behind the scenes by pyarrow (unless you change to some other engine).  Traditionally, the `group_by` would then be handled by directly by pandas (well, maybe numpy) but pyarrow has some experimental compute APIs as well if you wanted to try doing everything in pyarrow.

> Eventhough I haven't used dask just wondering if this kind of situation is handled in dask as they perform it lazily.

In my understanding (I don't have a ton of experience with dask), when you say...

```
df_2002 = df[df.year == 2002]
df_2002.groupby(["state", "gender"])["last_name"].count()
```

...in a dask dataframe then dask will figure out that it can apply pushdown filters and predicates and it will do so when loading the data.  So dask takes care of figuring out what filters you should apply and what columns you need to load.  This saves you from having to figure it out yourself ahead of time.

Complete example (you can use `strace` to verify that it is only loading one of the two parquet files and only part of that file):

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pandas as pd

import shutil

shutil.rmtree('/tmp/new_dataset')
tab = pa.Table.from_pydict({
    "year": ["2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003"],
    "state": [ "HI",   "HI",   "HI",   "HI",   "CO",   "CO",   "HI",   "HI",   "CO",   "CO",   "CO",   "CO"],
    "gender": [ "M",    "F",   None,    "F",    "M",    "F",   None,    "F",    "M",    "F",    "M",    "F"],
 "last_name": ["Smi", "Will", "Stev", "Stan",  "Smi", "Will", "Stev", "Stan",  "Smi", "Will", "Stev", "Stan"],
    "bonus": [    0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,      8,      9,     10,     11]
})
ds.write_dataset(tab, '/tmp/new_dataset', format='parquet', partitioning=['year'], partitioning_flavor='hive')

df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/new_dataset', filters=[[('year','=', 2002)]], columns=['year', 'state', 'gender', 'last_name'])
df_2002 = df[df.year == 2002]
print(df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["last_name"].count())
```

Disclaimer: You are asking about a number of technologies here.  I work pretty closely with the Apache Arrow project and thus my answer may be biased in that direction.

Comment: Thanks @Pace for an excellent answer. I was unaware about passing filters in arrow. I got 2 questions, 1) If I dont pass `filters` and `columns` does arrow query optimizer automatically able to push down filters and projections (like in duckDB (runs on arrow I guess ?) and spark) based on the following transformations ? `df_2002 = df[df.year == 2002]
print(df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["last_name"].count())`

2. Can you please tell me how to use strace or any articles that I can refer ?

Comment: Coming from Dask-land, I don't think Dask directly figures out the appropriate calls to `read_parquet`.  But it does support column pruning and predicate-pushdown-filtering similar to pandas (using both pyarrow & fasparquet engines), with lazy evaluations. See some benchmarks here: https://coiled.io/blog/parquet-file-column-pruning-predicate-pushdown/

Comment: Thanks @pavithraes !  I will update the wording of my answer a bit.  As for the other questions.  1) I don't know what the "arrow query optimizer" is.  Pyarrow does not have a query optimizer.  Yes, duckdb (and datafusion) are able to figure out optimized queries against R (today from SQL but later from Substrait which might open to other sources, e.g. Ibis).  I don't know much about spark.  2) strace is a Linux command to view what system calls a process makes (e.g. open and read).  It requires a good knowledge of Linux's API to use.  I'm not sure what a good resource would be.

Comment: @Pace Thank you. I think I am bit confused here. I raised a ticket for rarrow https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/12568 and it's mentioned that the arrow support the pushdowns without duckDB. So is this something specific to the rarrow and is not the case with pyarrow that we discussed here ?

Comment: Here are the PRs for Dask to implement this functionality #8692 and #8633. https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8692 https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8633

Comment: @Pace How can I become a member of arrow mailing list (like this one https://lists.apache.org/list.html?github@arrow.apache.org) ? and get some help if I got some questions ? Couple of questions are coming up as I learn more.

Comment: You probably don't want that specific list (github@ is the mailing list for all Github changes and can be pretty noisy).  The most common mailing lists are `user@` (for questions about using Arrow) and `dev@` (for questions about developing Arrow).  Send an email to user-subscribe@arrow.apache.org with no subject and no body to subscribe to the user@ mailing list (and dev-subscribe@arrow.apache.org for the dev@ mailing list)